# Can't copy from page when code snippet editor is opened

Tags: support, stack-snippets

When I want to copy code or text from the question page into the code snippet editor, I can't do so since the popup dialog is blocking access to the underlying text.

[image: code snippet blocker]

I can copy the text before I open up the code snippet editor, but if I want to copy more text or code that I didn't get the first time, I have to open up a new tab instead and grab it from there.

What's the best way for doing that?

Closing the popup will make the content already sitting in the code snippet editor to be lost.

How can I copy something from a post (question/answer) to code snippet editor, after I opened it?